# Qt TCP client cant show image received

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp

so im trying to code a TCPserver and a tcp client. The servers sends some pictures and the client load them as a pixmap in a label. I am able to connect to server,send data. My clients seem to receive some but never shows the picture.

I think my logic is good but it never works

**SERVER side**

clientthread.h

```
private:
    int socketDescriptor;
    int m_indDerniereImage;
    bool m_quit;
    QByteArray getByteArray(int indice);
    QString getNumNomFichier(int inndImages);
```

clientthread.cpp

```
void ClientThread::run()
{

    while(m_quit == false)
    {
        //Vérifier si notre image est à jour.
        if (m_indDerniereImage != g_indImage)
        {
            m_indDerniereImage = g_indImage;
            QByteArray bEnvoi = getByteArray(m_indDerniereImage);
            m_tcpSocket->write(bEnvoi);
            m_tcpSocket->flush();
        }
    }

}


QByteArray ClientThread::getByteArray(int indice)
{
    QString pathimage = g_PathDossierImage +  + "sintel_trailer_" + "0339" + ".jpg";
    QPixmap pixmapimage(pathimage);
    QByteArray bImage;
    QBuffer buffer(&bImage);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    pixmapimage.save(&buffer, "JPG");
    buffer.close();
    buffer.deleteLater();
    return bImage;
}

QString ClientThread::getNumNomFichier(int indImages)
{

    if (indImages < 10)
        return "000" + QString::number(indImages);
    else if(indImages < 100)
        return "00" + QString::number(indImages);
    else if(indImages < 1000)
        return "0" + QString::number(indImages);
    else
        return QString::number(indImages);
}


void ClientThread::onStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState status)
{
    if (status == QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState)
    {
        g_nbclients--;
        m_quit = true;
    }
}
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

streamerthread.h

```
class StreamerThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    StreamerThread(QObject *parent);
    void run();

private:
    QByteArray m_baImage; 
    bool m_quit; /cours de fermeture.

private slots:
    void slotQuit(); 

signals:
    void signalNouvelleImage(QByteArray baImage); 
private :
    QTcpSocket socket;
};
```

streamerthread.cpp

```
void StreamerThread::run()
{
    QByteArray buffReception;
//port et ip a hardcoder
    int port=4000;
    QString IP="127.0.0.1";

    socket.connectToHost(IP,port);
    socket.waitForConnected(15000);
    socket.waitForReadyRead(8000);
    while(m_quit==0)
    {
        if(socket.canReadLine())
        {
            buffReception=socket.readAll();
            m_baImage=buffReception;
            if(buffReception.size()>0)
                emit(signalNouvelleImage(m_baImage));
        }
    }
    socket.disconnect();

}
```

I dont know if i need to do something between each pictures received or what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to the thread on the client side and it worked im getting some pictures now.
in **streamerthread.cpp**

```
void StreamerThread::run()
{
    QByteArray monImage;
//port et ip a hardcoder
    int port=4000;
    QString IP="127.0.0.1";
    socket.connectToHost(IP, port);
    socket.waitForConnected(15000);
    socket.waitForReadyRead(8000);

    //Écouter et recevoir du serveur
    while(m_quit==0)
    {
        socket.waitForReadyRead(30000);
        if(socket.bytesAvailable() > 0)
        {
            monImage=socket.read(70000);
            m_baImage=monImage;
            emit(signalNouvelleImage(m_baImage));
       }
    }
    socket.disconnectFromHost();
    socket.close();

}
```